# Timing in OpenMPI

Tags: c++, timing, openmpi

Quick question about timing in OpenMPI. I see that with `qstat -a` I can show the wall time, and with `qstat` I can see the CPU time. Is it possible to have these two values written to the output file when the job is done so I can check the performance of my code?

Comment: Why don't you use `MPI_Wtime` for measuring elapsed time?

Comment: @xeroqu I think he also wants the user and kernel times?

Comment: @niklasfi Yeah that's exactly what I want

Comment: @niklasfi I see, alright then.